# Discover site url during or after the build

Tags: java, maven, maven-site-plugin

I would like to relate a Maven artifact to its site. Therefore, I need to get the actual URL where the site is deployed to (to write that information to a database). Since this URL not only depends on GAV, but also on multi-module structure, you cannot easily compute it without analysing parent POMs etc.

Is it possible (by some Maven goal) to get the site URL from a given POM?

Can I output the required information from the `site` or `site-deploy` goal?

Comment: Maybe one approach would be to find out the value of the url parameter. Can this be done through `properties:write-project-properties`? I am not able to run it on the command line.